# Generating a changelog with conventional-changelog-writer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, conventional-commits, conventional-changelog

I'm trying to use 
[conventional-changelog-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conventional-changelog-cli) to generate a changelog.

These are some the example outputs provided in the packages `README.md`.

- https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog/blob/master/packages/conventional-changelog/CHANGELOG.md
- https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
- https://github.com/btford/grunt-conventional-changelog/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
- https://github.com/btford/grunt-conventional-changelog/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

And they line up with what I'm trying to get it to do, which is group the commits by the version number.

So for example if under version `1.0.0` there are three commits, then they will render under that version and then if we bump the version to `1.0.1` and make new commits and render the changelog, those commits will show up under that version.

So this is what I've tried.

```
npm install -g conventional-changelog-cli
mkdir cl && cd cl && npm init -y && git init
git add . && git commit -m "fix: add project scaffolding"
conventional-changelog -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s
```

After this is done the changelog looks like this:

```
# 1.0.0 (2024-03-15)


### Bug Fixes

* project scaffolding f2da8ba
```

Next I bump to `1.0.1` and we add a `index.js` file like this and rerun the changelog generation this.

```
touch index.js
git add . && git commit -m "feat: add index.js with hello world logging"

conventional-changelog -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s
```

And now the changelog looks like this:

```
## 1.0.1 (2024-03-15)


### Bug Fixes

* add project scaffolding 38bc9ba


### Features

* add index.js with hello world logging 289395a



# 1.0.0 (2024-03-15)


### Bug Fixes

* add project scaffolding 38bc9ba
```

And as can be seen this part is repeated under version `1.0.1`:

```
### Bug Fixes

* add project scaffolding 38bc9ba
```

How do we run the cli so that it does not duplicate content under new versions?