# Get release-it to put each new commit under the corresponding release version in CHANGELOG.md

Tags: git, release-it

If we run release-it for multiple commits corresponding to different release version numbers it duplicates the commits in `CHANGELOG.md` under each version number.

Here's an example.

```
## 1.2.0 (2024-03-20)


### Features

* add commit linting 5eee5b0
* add release it changelog generation 80e627c

## 1.1.0 (2024-03-20)


### Features

* add release it changelog generation 80e627c
```

In this case commit 80e627c is regenerated under version `1.2.0` also.

How do we get release-it to put exclude previous commits from new version numbers?

I'd like to get the changelog to end up like this:

```
## 1.2.0 (2024-03-20)


### Features

* add commit linting 5eee5b0

## 1.1.0 (2024-03-20)

### Features

* add release it changelog generation 80e627c
```

To reproduce the behavior perform the following steps:

```
mkdir ri && cd ri && npm init -y && git init
echo "node_modules" > .gitignore
npm i -D release-it @release-it/conventional-changelog
npm init release-it
```

The release-it config in `package.json` should look like this:

```
"release-it": {
    "git": {
      "commitMessage": "chore: release ${version}"
    },
    "github": {
      "release": true
    },
    "npm": {
      "publish": false
    },
    "plugins": {
      "@release-it/conventional-changelog": {
        "infile": "CHANGELOG.md",
        "preset": {
          "name": "conventionalcommits",
          "type": [
            { "type": "feat", "section": "Features"},
            { "type": "fix", "section": "Bug Fixes"}
          ]
        }
      }
    } 
  }
```

Test it.

```
git add . && git commit -m "feat: add release it changelog generation"
npx release-it --no-git

touch extra-file

git add . && git commit -m "feat: add commit linting"
npx release-it --no-git --debug
```

Comment: That looks like a bug, or is there a case where the duplication makes sense?

Comment: I was thinking it's a bug too ... I asked about it also on their issues list and someone else is seeing it as well ... https://github.com/release-it/release-it/issues/1077

Comment: Conventional Changelog Writer does the same thing and I wonder if the release-it plugin is using that under the hood ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78166310/generating-a-changelog-with-conventional-changelog-writer

Comment: Also reported it on the plugins issue page.  https://github.com/release-it/conventional-changelog/issues/86

Comment: When you disable the tagging with `--no-git`, how exactly is it supposed to work out which commits are in which release?

Comment: It can read it from package.json in the git commit history.  That's how each `## 1.2.0 (2024-03-20)` type header is generated.